# Stream processor definition

Tags: parallel-computing, graphics, signal-processing

I'm looking for an actual definition of a stream processing unit (SPU), preferably sourced. The context is not specifically graphics cards.

I can find many, many articles explaining what they contain, or what they do in specific cases, but I need a definition for an informal class presentation. I have a general sense of what they are, but can't find much literature to back that up. However, even an informal definition would help.

Would really appreciate any input.